# How to add attribute for child node in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<_POSDW-POSTR_CREATEMULTIPLE04>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">        
        <_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP>
            <_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION>
                <RETAILSTOREID>C10</RETAILSTOREID>
                <BUSINESSDAYDATE>11182015</BUSINESSDAYDATE>
                <PARTNERQUALIFIER>1</PARTNERQUALIFIER>
                <TRANSACTIONTYPECODE>MS01</TRANSACTIONTYPECODE>
                <WORKSTATIONID>001</WORKSTATIONID>
                <TRANSACTIONSEQUENCENUMBER>001007071</TRANSACTIONSEQUENCENUMBER>
                <BEGINDATETIMESTAMP>11182015</BEGINDATETIMESTAMP>
                <ENDDATETIMESTAMP>11182015</ENDDATETIMESTAMP>
                <OPERATORQUALIFIER>1</OPERATORQUALIFIER>
                <OPERATORID>10006</OPERATORID>
                <TRANSACTIONCURRENCY>VND</TRANSACTIONCURRENCY>
            </_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION>           
        </_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP>
    </IDOC>
</_POSDW-POSTR_CREATEMULTIPLE04>
```

I am try to add attribute : SEGMENT="1" for each node

using :

```
<xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="SEGMENT">1</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
```

The result only :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<_POSDW-POSTR_CREATEMULTIPLE04>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">        
        <_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP SEGMENT="1">
            <_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION>
                <RETAILSTOREID>C10</RETAILSTOREID>
                <BUSINESSDAYDATE>11182015</BUSINESSDAYDATE>
                <PARTNERQUALIFIER>1</PARTNERQUALIFIER>
                <TRANSACTIONTYPECODE>MS01</TRANSACTIONTYPECODE>
                <WORKSTATIONID>001</WORKSTATIONID>
                <TRANSACTIONSEQUENCENUMBER>001007071</TRANSACTIONSEQUENCENUMBER>
                <BEGINDATETIMESTAMP>11182015</BEGINDATETIMESTAMP>
                <ENDDATETIMESTAMP>11182015</ENDDATETIMESTAMP>
                <OPERATORQUALIFIER>1</OPERATORQUALIFIER>
                <OPERATORID>10006</OPERATORID>
                <TRANSACTIONCURRENCY>VND</TRANSACTIONCURRENCY>
            </_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION>           
        </_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP>
    </IDOC>
</_POSDW-POSTR_CREATEMULTIPLE04>
```

There are missing attribute for node : _POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION

Please help me add attribute : SEGMENT="1" to _POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION

Thanks,
Cuong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use identity template, plus one more template which supposed add `SEGMENT="1"` attribute to specific set of elements i.e `_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP` and `_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION` :

```
<xsl:template match="_POSDW-E1POSTR_CREATEMULTIP|_POSDW-E1BPTRANSACTION">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="SEGMENT">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo`](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYif)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you. it worked. The transfer tool very useful.